# Calling callback function in directive doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-controller

I want the directive to pass a value to the callback function (that was defined in the controller). The function is never called, though, and I have no clue why.

**HTML:**

```
<input type='file' fileread success="fileUploaded(data)" name="myFile" id="myFile" />
```

**DIRECTIVE:**

```
myApp.directive('fileread', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            callBack: '&success',
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.callBack({data: "test"});
        }
    };
});
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.fileUploaded = function(data){
        console.log(data);
    };
})
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/v6r9L6g3/4/

Comment: You're missing the `ng-app` and `ng-controller` directives in your Fiddle. Once you add those it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing ng-app and ng-controller in your html
your html must be

```html
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input type='file' fileread success="fileUploaded(data)" name="myFile" id="myFile" />
</div>
```

Above will work fine 
Alternatively you can use your directive as follow

```
  myApp.directive('fileread', function() {
    return {
     scope: {
    success: '&',
    },
link: function (scope, element) {

    scope.success({data: "test"});
}
};
});
```

And

here is working example http://jsfiddle.net/31rpuobL/

Comment: There's no need to change the directive - it was just the missing `ng-app` and `ng-controller` directives.

Comment: Your answer seemed to imply that you can't rename properties and methods on an isolate scope, but you most definitely can. Just wanted to make sure that anyone who might read this in the future isn't confused thinking that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only one trouble with execution of your code was that input have to be surrounded by div with `ng-controller` directive on it. Like following

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type='file' fileread success="fileUploaded(data)" name="myFile" id="myFile" />
</div>
```

And everything just works perfect.